# Benchmark class range for classifying sentiment analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing sentiment analysis for documents. Theoretically i need to classify the document in to three groups. Positive ,Negative and Neutral. My  results are produced between `-1(negative) and +1(positive), obviously 0 is neutral.`

> Is that right if i classified the range as [-1 to -0.33]Negative
>   ,[-0.34 to +0.33]Neutral and  [+0.34 to +1]Positive.

Or is there is any benchmark range for classifying sentiment range.
BTW: I'm using python [TextBlob sentiment API](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.TextBlob.sentiment) to analyse the [Enron email dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/).

Comment: Without revealing your data and your methods, your question really doesn't make much sense. My suggestion would be to plot your performance on your training data and establish what boundaries make sense for you completely empirically.

Comment: Thank you tripleee.  Please check my edited Question.

Comment: Without a graph of your actual numbers, we'd have to repeat your experiment to obtain any useful guesstimate. From my limited experience with this particular corpus, I would expect "neutral" to dominate, so maybe you'll want to narrow the middle band to capture even more mildly positive/negative sentiments out of the dull grey inertia of bulk "please read the attached Excel sheet" messages.

Comment: If you are lucky, you *might* be able to find notches like in the lower picture here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8leUx.jpg (notice the arrows).

Comment: ya my results are exactly looks like your example... (unfortunately i can share the results because i'm using my companies personal email threads to analyse ;).  )

Comment: A graph on that level would hardly be confidential, and would finally give us something concrete to say; but up to your judgement, obviously.

Comment: Ya i understand... these are from few of my documents 0.17059 
0.02328 
0.17169 
0.02235 
0.11956 
0.10761 
0.14888 
0.11787 
0.08438 
0.03379 graph for this https://goo.gl/photos/EnTMQhqPrq6GtFCr6

Comment: So would you rank some of those subjectively as positive, or all neutral, as your proposed scale would have it?

Comment: Of course this what my problem... each and every output produce a score which more than 0. therefore, there is no class called negative. i'm looking for a threshold value to divide neutral and positive only. i can obviously say that, its not negative. but  As i proposed in the question, dividing the [-1 to 1] bin into three bins seems not appropriate.also i don't find a prior experiment which threshold the bin in to two. If i had it maybe i can use 1-R algorithm to find the divider.

Comment: Sounds more like a standard GIGO problem then - your training corpus is flawed or you are doing something wrong. Does it fail to cross-validate negative training samples, too?

Comment: Ok i'll try n-fold cross validation and let you know thank you.

Comment: Simple internal (basically 1-fold) cross-validation should suffice more than enough for testing whether your toolchain is working.